What would be an example of a question on-topic here that is not off-topic elsewhere in SE?
Ever since Eco SE got in beta, I don't see much point in keeping Quant SE around other than having another place to ask math questions when you reach your limit on Math SE if Eco SE graduates from beta.
Some finance questions are too basic for Quant SE but no finance question is too advanced for Eco SE, so it seems. It seems like any question on-topic here is on-topic somewhere else in SE. Suppose Eco SE graduates from beta, is there still any purpose for Quant SE?
Perhaps I'm not understanding something about SE right because there's this and this Please point out any misconception I may have made.
Also, please give me an example of a question on-topic here that is not off-topic elsewhere in stackexchange or stack overflow.

I think that to some extent you're right but this is a general problem in the StackExchange environment.
I mean, you could argue that statistics [stats.se] are part of [maths.se], for example, and that the separation could come solely from tagging. StackOverflow handles some many different programming questions in different programming languages and paradigms after all.
So I think it kind of comes down to "is the topic wide enough to deserve its own site" and this is answered by the stats of the beta site but I'd agree that we could create a bigger site Finance/Economics where everything is on topic.
Here are questions that I think are good examples for this sites:

How do you mix quantitative asset allocation with qualitative views?
Innovative ways of visualizing financial data
Option pricing before Black-Scholes
All pricing questions although you'll argue they can go to math or economics (and precisely, which one then?)

